# What scale should a detected SIFT point be extracted at?

Tags: computer-vision, local-features, sift

I've heard this from a few different researchers but I can't find a definitive value.  Given the "scale" extracted by David Lowe's SIFT detector, we need to extract a descriptor at a specific scale.

Is it 6 times the detector "scale"?  3?  1?  I've heard conflicting values.  What is known about this?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly what you are asking --
In general, the feature is found at the same scale as the SIFT detector says, but
in David Lowe's SIFT, the image is pre-smoothed with sigma: 0.5, so, you need to "subtract" this amount of smoothing from the sigma, so the "real" scale could be:

sqrt(sigma^2 - 0.5^2)

where sigma is the scale the feature was found at.
you have an excellent implementation of SIFT detector and descriptor at: www.vlfeat.org